# What is IOS retain do at backend

Tags: objective-c, ios, copy, retain, retaincount

Consider I am allocating an object.  Please see the below image

[image]

In the above image *myObject is a pointer.  It is referring to an space allocated to that object.  When we retain the object,  I like to know what it does at backend.  Also I like to know why we are doing that.

Also when we release it how it works at backend.

I also like to know what happens at backend when we copy an object.

I am really sorry if my question is so basic.

Comment: Can you really not find a source for this information?  Its freely available in many places on the web.  And what do you mean by backend?  Read up on obj C there are tons of resources and Im sure this question has been answered a thousand times on SO already.

Comment: I searched,  people are saying that it gives the ownership etc...  The backend means the operating system ios.

Comment: If the exact question is already answered please provide the link,  and i ill delete the question.  Thank you..

Comment: Not my job man, and a google search on obj C retain and release semantics will return a million results.  My question is why cant YOU search it and find it?

Comment: Ok, thank you @stackmonster ill search it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What retain actually does under the hood is:

1. Take a global lock in the objc runtime
2. Look up a hash table entry based on the pointer to the object being retained
3. Increment a counter in that entry
4. Release the lock

I don't expect this to be all that helpful in practice, but I think it's what you were asking for.

Comment: Thank you @Catfish..  How will be the hashtable like address to value..  I agree with it.  I like to know what happen when we retain.. like will the object gets recreated in another location?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you're asking there, sorry.

Comment: I am trying to ask that when we do the retain,  what is happening in the object memory is that increasing.

Comment: All it does is increment a number. That's it. Nothing happens to the object.

Comment: Thank you @catfish Why we are doing that, why cant we survive with one alloc why do we need retain.  I am sorry if my question is so basic.  Thanks a lot for helping me understand.

Comment: Because an object can have more than one owner. Each owner retains the object, that way it's only deallocated when they're all done with it, rather than when the first one is.

Comment: Thank you Verymuch you made me much clear... Thanks a lot..:)